# Delete string of characters from HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I send get requests to a site and sometimes the return has strings such as the following at the top above the HTML, causing jQuery to error

For example

```
4341-b087-58848cd597a7%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|<div>Div</div>
```

Which would result in

```
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 4341-b087-58848cd597a7%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|jquery.js:1473 Sizzle.errorjquery.js:2087 Sizzle.tokenizejquery.js:2488 Sizzle.selectjquery.js:879 Sizzlejquery.js:2704 jQuery.fn.extend.findjquery.js:2821 jQuery.fn.initjquery.js:73 jQuerygear.js:26 (anonymous function)gear.js:21 (anonymous function)jquery.js:3119 firejquery.js:3231 self.fireWithjquery.js:9275 donejquery.js:9685 callback
```

Each time the strings have something in common; they all begin with `4`, end with `%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|`

How can I check if the text `%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|` is in the page, and if so remove everything from `4` to `%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|` (including those) so it does not error?
My code is something like this

```
$.get(url).done(function(data) {
    callback(data.replace(/img/gi, "flip");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with that response that's giving you that error?

Comment: (In the callback) `var Item = $(data).find("#ct100").attr("href"); console.log(Item);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regexp:

```
data = data.replace(/^4.*%26mode%3d%26code%3d500\|/, '');
```

Or you can wrap the whole thing in a DIV:

```
var Item = $('<div>', { html: data }).find("#ct100").attr("href");
```

Comment: Same issue, just tested. Thanks for the help though

Comment: I forgot to escape the `|` in the regexp.

Comment: The wrapping in a div works great, but 30% of the time Item is undefined :(

Comment: Well, that probably means there's no `#ct100` element in the returned data. Nothing you can do about that with this code.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is at the beginning of the response, simple & fast:

```
$.get(url).done(function(data) {
    data = data.split('%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even use javascript `string` functions to get rid of this:

```
var pos = data.lastIndexOf("%26mode%3d%26code%3d500|");
var reqPos = pos + 24; //last position of above string + number of chars in above string
var result = str.slice(reqPos);
alert(result); //will give you expected output
```